# Move files from subfolders into parent folder

Tags: shell, directory, mv

I downloaded a lot of files from S3, dumped them all into a new folder called `contracts`. Now, within contracts, each file is in its own named (as numbers) folder, ie `55`, `66`, etc.

Looking for a script to take all files within all these subfolders, move them into parent folder (/contracts), and delete the then empty folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yes | cp -a /contract/*/* /contract
```

/contract means your contract directory resides in / but you can change the path wherever you want e.g. `yes | cp -a /var/contract/*/* /var/contract`

This is from and to path. Please note change cp to mv if you want to move instead of copy. In your case this will work `yes | cp -a contracts/*/* contracts`

Comment: Thanks. But I get `cp: /contracts/*/*: No such file or directory`

Comment: EDIT: it worked removing the backslashes, as: `yes | cp -a contracts/*/* contracts`. Please edit your answer and I'll mark as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanRebo its really pity when you need our help then replying immediately and we are helping you to give our time of earliest convenience but when you we fix your problem then you even don't bother to mark our answer or any of our comment that is not fair at all

Comment: I just wasn't on here for a few days, being the weekend and all. Thanks for your help! Marked.

Answer (score 2):

I would do (from just outside of `contracts`):

```
mkdir contracts2 #create a sister folder
find contracts -type f -print0 | #find all files in contracts
    xargs -0 -I{} cp -l {} contracts2/ #hardlink them flatly to contracts2
```

Now if everything looks good (check with `tree contracts2`), you can 
`rm -rf contracts` and `mv contracts2 contracts`.

This should be both extremely fast (hardlinking is extremely fast and it'll probably execute only one instance of `cp`) and safe (you don't lose the original directory until you run `rm -rf` on it).

Answer (score 1):

You can move all files using `find` and `mv` together with the `-exec` option:

```
find /path/to/contracts -type f -exec mv -i '{}' /path/to/contracts \;
```

By providing the `-i` option to `mv`, it will prompt before overwriting files with identical names. If there are many files with identical names, you may want to create a short script to rename the files on the fly to avoid the user interaction.